# Alternative for sapply

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, sapply

I am using the following code in R :

```
df$max_col<- sapply(df$col, function(x) ifelse(x == "", 0, strsplit(as.character(x), "", perl = TRUE)[[1]] %>% as.numeric %>% max(na.rm = T)))
```

This code basically breaks a string like "123456" and turns it into numeric and returns the max value from it. Now, I have a column full of strings like these and this code runs fine till the data size is low. But when the data size is 25 million rows (which I currently am dealing with) this code becomes very slow. Is there any alternative for this code through which I can get the max value from the string stored in a new column?

Comment: Why `strsplit` ? Can you provide a small example of your data?

Comment: have you tried to figure out which component takes the most time -- it needn't be sapply. (could be `strsplit` or  `ifelse` or  `as.character` or `às.numeric`

Comment: could try something like this: `apply(sapply(0:9, function(Y) grepl(Y,x)),2,which.max)` (where `x` is a vector, something like `x<-c("123", "12345", "56690239")`

Comment: unlist(lapply(..)) will be (generally) faster than sapply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer based on my comment above (but I've modified the code so that it actually works):

```
x <- c("123", "224", "221", "1912323", "445")
apply(sapply(1:9, function(p) grepl(p, x)), 1, function(k) max(which(k)))
# the above will work if 0 is never the largest  number in any cell
```

A more generalized version:

```
doit <- function(x) apply(sapply(0:9, function(p) grepl(p, x)), 1, function(k) max(which(k)))-1
x <- c("123", "224", "221", "1912323", "445", "000")
doit(x)
# [1] 3 4 2 9 5 0
```

This is about 3 times faster than the original code using strsplit ... but I'm sure there is room for improvement. Umm ... actually, I'm gonna try with `strsplit` again:

```
doit3 <- function(.) sapply(strsplit(.,""), max)
doit3(x)
# [1] "3" "4" "2" "9" "5" "0"
```

This is about 5 times faster than my previous approach. So the problem was not in `sapply` or `strsplit` but in the other components. If you need to convert it to numeric, add `as.numeric` to the outer layer, this won't take much extra time:

```
doit4 <- function(.) as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(.,""), max))
> doit4(x)
# [1] 3 4 2 9 5 0
```

Comment: what if i want to take the count of ">0" entries in the string?

Comment: you mean both `222` and `111` resulting in `3` but `099` resulting in `2`? a simple way would be `nchar(gsub("0","",x))` -- but this presumes that the string contains only digits

Comment: I suppose, `nchar(gsub("[^1-9]","",x))` would be a more general approach (it would not count e.g. blanks and letters if they occur in a string)

Answer (score 1):

Converting to an integer then computing the digits using `%%` and `%/%` appears to be fastest for a 25,000,000 length vector:

```
a <- as.character(sample(1:1e6, size = 25e6, replace = TRUE))

use_grepl <- function(x) {
  o <- integer(length(x))
  o[grep('1', x, fixed = TRUE)] <- 1L
  o[grep('2', x, fixed = TRUE)] <- 2L
  o[grep('3', x, fixed = TRUE)] <- 3L
  o[grep('4', x, fixed = TRUE)] <- 4L
  o[grep('5', x, fixed = TRUE)] <- 5L
  o[grep('6', x, fixed = TRUE)] <- 6L
  o[grep('7', x, fixed = TRUE)] <- 7L
  o[grep('8', x, fixed = TRUE)] <- 8L
  o[grep('9', x, fixed = TRUE)] <- 9L
  o
}

use_strsplit <- function(x) {
  tbl19 <- as.character(1:9)
  vapply(strsplit(x, split = "", fixed = TRUE),
         function(v) {
           max(fmatch(v, table = tbl19, nomatch = 0L))
         },
         0L)
}

use_mod <- function(xx) {

  nth_digit_of <- function (x, n) {
    {x %% 10^n} %/% 10^{n - 1L}
  }
  v <- as.integer(xx)
  most_digits <- as.integer(ceiling(log10(max(v))) + 1)
  o <- nth_digit_of(v, 1L)
  for (vj in 2:most_digits) {
    o <- pmax.int(o, nth_digit_of(v, vj)) 
  }
  as.integer(o)
}


doit4 <- function(V) as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(V, ""), max))

bench::mark(use_mod(a), use_grepl(a), doit4(a))
# A tibble: 3 x 14
  expression   min  mean median   max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc n_itr total_time result memory time 
  <chr>      <bch> <bch> <bch:> <bch>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl> <int>   <bch:tm> <list> <list> <lis>
1 use_mod(a) 14.4s 14.4s  14.4s 14.4s    0.0693    2.61GB     3     1      14.4s <int ~ <Rpro~ <bch~
2 use_grepl~ 38.2s 38.2s  38.2s 38.2s    0.0262    1.32GB     0     1      38.2s <int ~ <Rpro~ <bch~
3 doit4(a)   56.5s 56.5s  56.5s 56.5s    0.0177    1.18GB     7     1      56.5s <dbl ~ <Rpro~ <bch~
```